# В чем отличие методов от сообщений objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Чем отличается процедура от функции и функция от метода, вплоне понятно. А вот, что касается понятия "сообщения" в objective-c, - не совсем. Сейчас я использую их, исключительно подразумевая, что это то же самое, что и метод в ОО языках. Так ли это? И если есть какие-то интересные отличия сообщений от методов, как их можно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этом можно почитать [здесь](http://www.chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf) - конкретно пункты 3.3 и 3.4.

3.4 Messages and transmission
3.4.1 Sending a message to nil
3.4.2 Delegating a message to an unknown object
3.4.3 Forwarding: handling an unknown message
3.4.4 Downcasting

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение в Objective-C это то же самое что и метод в C++. Посылка сообщения - то же самое, что вызов метода. Это на идеологическом уровне. На практике же, конечно, есть отличия, и я насчитал их целых два:

1) Сообщения более динамичны, чем методы. То есть, например, компилятор не даст вам вызвать несуществующий метод, но даст послать любое сообщение (он выдаст варнинг, поэтому в objective-c нужно всегда внимательно смотреть в сообщения компилятора).

2) Из-за динамичности посылка сообщения влечет за собой накладные расходы, и занимает больше времени, чем вызов метода, поэтому в особо узких местах имеет смысл переходить на C++ (или на C)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, главное отличие сообщений от методов - это forwardInvocation. Это механизм обработки любого сообщения. То есть если мы посылаем сообщение некоторому объекту, но ни у кого из его иерархии не найдется селектора для обработки, то вызовется метод

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation;
```

NSInvocation - это специальная обертка, подробнее [здесь](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).